# Cannot click a radio button inside a span Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, radio-button

I am trying to click into a radio button inside a span. Trying to execute:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 


chromeDriver = webdriver.Chrome()
chromeDriver.get('https://www.flytap.com/pt-br/')

#Works Fine
chromeDriver.find_element_by_id('origin')
origin.click()
origin.clear()
origin.send_keys('(RIO) Rio De Janeiro -  todos os aeroportos , Brasil')
    origin.click()

#Where I got the error
milesBox = chromeDriver.find_element_by_id("booking-type-2").click()

#Also tried:
milesBox = chromeDriver.find_element_by_id("booking-type-2").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

#And, finally:
milesBox = chromeDriver.find_element_by_id("booking-type-2").send_keys(Keys.SPACE)
```

Here is the error I got:

```
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
```

HTML code:

```
<!-- Payment Methods START -->
                <fieldset id="booking-payment-drag" class="booking-payment">
                    <div class="toolbar-radio-wrapper">
                        <legend class="ipt-label">Reservar com:</legend>
                    </div>
                    <div class="toolbar-radio-wrapper">
                        <div class="radio">
                            <span class="checked"><input type="radio" id="booking-type-1" name="booking-type" value="1" checked></span>
                        </div>
                        <label for="booking-type-1" class="ipt-label">Dinheiro</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="toolbar-radio-wrapper js-country-not-eligible">
                        <div class="radio">
                            <span class=""><input type="radio" id="booking-type-2" name="booking-type" value="2"></span>
                        </div>
                        <label for="booking-type-2" class="ipt-label">Milhas</label>
                    </div>
                        <div class="toolbar-radio-wrapper">
                            <div class="radio is-disabled js-country-eligible">
                                <span class=""><input type="radio" id="booking-type-3" name="booking-type" value="3" disabled></span>
                            </div>
                            <label for="booking-type-3" class="ipt-label">Miles&Cash</label>
                                                        </div>
                </fieldset>
```

Comment: are you sure "booking-type-2" is visible when you are trying to click on it. in your case it doesn't seems to be appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to click on the radio button beside the `<label>` with text as **Milhas** you can use the following line of code :

```
chromeDriver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='booking-type-2' and @name='booking-type']").click()
```

Comment: Thanks, DebajanB, it was really heplful :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `origin` element's dropdown covers the radio button you are trying to click. Maybe you could change the order of operations though? Clicking the `destination` element also opens up the section where the radio button is but it doesn't seem to cover it. This is a quick example of clicking that radio button and then you could go fillout the `origin` input after.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.flytap.com/pt-br/')

destination = driver.find_element_by_id('destination')
destination.click()

miles_box = driver.find_element_by_id('booking-type-2')
miles_box.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this xpath

```
//div[@class='radio']//span//input[@id='booking-type-1']

//div[@class='radio']//span//input[@id='booking-type-2']

//div[@class='radio is-disabled js-country-eligible']//span//input[@id='booking-type-3']
```